# Finding Sum in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

From the XML Document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <Data>
   <Products>
      <Product ProductId="1001" ProductName="ProductA" ProductPrice="123.45" /> 
      <Product ProductId="1002" ProductName="ProductB" ProductPrice="100.45" /> 
  </Products>
  ....
```

How to use "Sum" to find the sum of `ProductPrice?`

When i use

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Product.xml");

var sum =
          from tot in (int)doc.Descendants("Product").
                       Attributes("ProductPrice").Sum()
                       select tot;
```

I receive Error : **"can not convert type system.xml.linq.xmlattribute to int"**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using a query expression here, but I think you want:

```
int sum = doc.Descendants("Product")
             .Sum(x => (int) x.Attribute("ProductPrice"));
```

The important point is that this uses the [overload of `Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx) which lets you specify a function to go from the source element to the integer value.

Comment: Thank you.I am new to Linq.So not quite familiar how to apply calculations.Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry we have to use (double) x.Attribute("ProductPrice") instead of int.

Comment: Are you sure you want double rather than decimal? Using float/double is rarely a good idea for prices. You'll run into rounding difficulties.